# Installer 5.7.11 is installing Community Edition 5.6.29

Tags: mysql

I feel like I'm missing something.  The Community Edition 5.7.11 is installing MySQL Server 5.6.29.  Windows edition (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

I notice on the Change History catalog in the Installer, that 5.7.11 was published on 2/5/16.   I see that 5.6.29 was ALSO published on that same date.

I'm wondering if there is a problem with the install package, or (more likely) with my understanding.  I'm sure I'm in error here and apologize, but I would appreciate enlightenment.